# Hue shift shader breaks alpha

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, cocos2d-x, shader

I am using cocos2dx. I have a Sprite which is set with a custom shader like this:

```
boss_1 = Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("Zombies/normal/0_0_0.png");
boss_1->setPosition(boss_1->getContentSize()/2.0f);
boss_1->setBlendFunc(cocos2d::BlendFunc::ALPHA_NON_PREMULTIPLIED);
boss_1->setGLProgramState(boss_1_state);
```

I have the following shader:

```
vec3 hueAdjust(vec3 color, float hueAdjust)
{
    const vec3  kRGBToYPrime = vec3 (0.299, 0.587, 0.114);
    const vec3  kRGBToI     = vec3 (0.596, -0.275, -0.321);
    const vec3  kRGBToQ     = vec3 (0.212, -0.523, 0.311);

    const vec3  kYIQToR   = vec3 (1.0, 0.956, 0.621);
    const vec3  kYIQToG   = vec3 (1.0, -0.272, -0.647);
    const vec3  kYIQToB   = vec3 (1.0, -1.107, 1.704);

    // Convert to YIQ
    float   YPrime  = dot (color, kRGBToYPrime);
    float   I      = dot (color, kRGBToI);
    float   Q      = dot (color, kRGBToQ);

    // Calculate the hue and chroma
    float   hue     = atan (Q, I);
    float   chroma  = sqrt (I * I + Q * Q);

    // Make the user's adjustments
    hue += hueAdjust;

    // Convert back to YIQ
    Q = chroma * sin (hue);
    I = chroma * cos (hue);

    // Convert back to RGB
    vec3    yIQ   = vec3 (YPrime, I, Q);
    color.r = dot (yIQ, kYIQToR);
    color.g = dot (yIQ, kYIQToG);
    color.b = dot (yIQ, kYIQToB);

    // Save the result
    return color;
}

void main()
{
    vec4 v_orColor = v_fragmentColor * texture2D(CC_Texture0, v_texCoord);

    // Hue

    vec3 hueAdjustedColor = hueAdjust(v_orColor.rgb, hue_value);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(hueAdjustedColor, v_orColor.a);
}
```

But the alpha seems to get lost and the sprite is rendered with a black background. (Although the hue shift works perfectly, since i can test it with a slider)

This only happens with the hueAdjust function. If I use this other function to change contrast/saturation/brightness, the alpha is preserved perfectly:

```
vec3 ContrastSaturationBrightness(vec3 color, float brt, float sat, float con)
{
    // Increase or decrease these values to adjust r, g and b color channels seperately
    const float AvgLumR = 0.5;
    const float AvgLumG = 0.5;
    const float AvgLumB = 0.5;

    const vec3 LumCoeff = vec3(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);

    vec3 AvgLumin = vec3(AvgLumR, AvgLumG, AvgLumB);
    vec3 brtColor = color * brt;
    vec3 intensity = vec3(dot(brtColor, LumCoeff));
    vec3 satColor = mix(intensity, brtColor, sat);
    vec3 conColor = mix(AvgLumin, satColor, con);
    return conColor;
}
```

Comment: what gfx card/driver and OS version you use? (It may be driver bug)

Comment: BTW you are missing: `[Fragment]
Compiler error
0(39) : error C1008: undefined variable "v_fragmentColor"
0(39) : error C1008: undefined variable "CC_Texture0"
0(39) : error C1008: undefined variable "v_texCoord"
0(43) : error C1008: undefined variable "hue_value"` may be there are internally added by framework you use ... I added `uniform vec4 v_fragmentColor;
uniform sampler2D CC_Texture0;
uniform vec2 v_texCoord;
uniform float hue_value;` then the compilation is OK.

Comment: Hey, sorry i hadn't seen your message until now. I'm using iOS 9.2 (13C75) on an iPhone 6s plus. And yeah what you say im missing is automatically added by cocos2dx.

Comment: It sounds like it might be a draw order issue. When does it render? Can you control the draw order? Eyeballing it, it looks like it should be fine, and I put it into Unity and it renders fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the algorithm in hueAdjust outputs negative colors or NaNs...

I got it working by replacing this line:

`vec3 hueAdjustedColor = hueAdjust(v_orColor.rgb, hue_value);`

with this one:

`vec3 hueAdjustedColor = max(hueAdjust(v_orColor.rgb, hue_value), 0.0);`

BTW, algorithm seems to be overcomplicated. Why do you converting colors like this RGB -> YIQ -> HSV -> YIQ -> RGB? You can convert RGB directly to HSV and vice versa without intermediate YIQ stage. Here is fast branchless algorithm for this: http://lolengine.net/blog/2013/07/27/rgb-to-hsv-in-glsl

Hope, it helps :)

Comment: This is it!, it worked by replacing the line you just mentioned, although i still don't understand why the rgb colors being negative or NaNs can affect the alpha channel it did solve my issue, do you happen to know why?. Oh and the reason why i change to YIQ is to rotate the Hue in that color space. The place where i originally took the code from mentioned rotating hue in hue space could cause some trouble sometimes so it recommended doing it like this. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Chiquis, I don't know why exactly this happens. I encountered a similar issue myself a while ago and that time googling didn't give me anything useful, so the only thing that I'm sure about is that if color components are out of [0.0; 1.0] range - weird things may happen. But I don't know what things gonna happen in each particular case and why they gonna happen :)

I think that's because of some low-level optimizations in the GPU chip.